# java can't connect to databases with an underscore in the name?

Tags: java, mysql, database

So let's say i have this string as my URL:
    `final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test_0";`
and then i try and run this line:
    `conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);`

Well if the URL would point to a 'test' database and not to 'test_0' or '64_database' it will work, but if i try the later names i get errors and stuff. so is there a way to make it process a URL with an underscore in it ?
Or is it the fact that it has numbers in it ?

Comment: Do you have permissions to access the database with the user/pass combination?

Comment: Underscores are allowed in database names [(reference)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html)

Comment: "errors and stuff" is not enough for us to help you

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing bad in underscore in database name. Neither in numbers. This isn't the problem why you cannot connect. Post stacktrace, please.

Comment: Those are the errors:`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.` Thing is that in php i can access this Database but in java i can't

Answer (score 0):

Oke I'm a noob, The problem was that i changed the port of the server from the default 3306 to 3036 so i made the change in the code to:
`final String DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3036/64_database";`  And now it works , weird thing is that on the database without the underscore it was connecting and i was able to even create tables although i couldn't find them in mysql query browser.